# Hyundai Santa fe 2013 4x4 knocking sound from the back of the car.

Tags: hyundai, noise, santa-fe

My Hyundai Santa fe 4wd is making a loud noise knocking noise from the back of the car. When I was checking the car I accidentally disconnected the (ABS) and the 4wd, then I took the car for a drive and the knocking sound disappeared. When I reconnected the systems the sound appeared again. I checked the rear bearings, the one on the right is tighter than the one on the left, and there is no problem with the breaks. What could be the problem?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'd suggest to help narrow it down, try and disconnect one and see if it still continues ... help you get to what's causing the noise, most likely.

Comment: "disconnected the (ABS) and the 4wd" exactly what was disconnected?